# bash - extglob 2nd "zero or more" operator not working

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, variable-substitution

Given:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ TEST="    z abcdefg";echo ">>${TEST#*( )z*( )}<<"
>> abcdefg<<
```

Why is there a space before the letter 'a'?  I would expect that the 2nd `*( )` would match the space, but it does not seams to do so.

I expected the equivalent of:

```
$ echo ">>$(echo -n "${TEST}" | perl -pe "s/^ *z *//g")<<"
>>abcdefg<<
```

The 2nd `*( )` matches if I specify the next following character (which is 'a'):

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ TEST="    z abcdefg";echo ">>${TEST#*( )z*( )a}<<"
>>bcdefg<<
```

Bash version:  `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`${TEST#...}` matches the shortest string, which is z followed by zero spaces.  You need `${TEST##...}`, the longest match.

Answer (score 5):

This is due to the interaction between the non-greedy substring removal and the type of pattern you're using.

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html),

> ```
> ?(pattern-list)
> ```
>
> Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns.
>
> ```
> *(pattern-list)
> ```
>
> Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns.
>
> ```
> +(pattern-list)
> ```
>
> Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.

From my favorite explanation on bash [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html),

> `${string#substring}`
>
> Deletes shortest match of `$substring` from front of `$string`.
>
> `${string##substring}`
>
> Deletes longest match of `$substring` from front of `$string`.

So, when you specify `${TEST#*( )z*( )}`, you're saying: "Please delete the shortest substring that has zero or more spaces, a `z`, then zero or more spaces.

Matching on the last space is longer than matching without it, so the last space is never matched.

To rectify this, you can either use `${TEST##*( )z*( )}` to match the longest prefix ending with zero or more spaces or `${TEST#*( )z+( )}` to match the shortest prefix ending with one or more spaces (which is functionally equivalent to matching the shortest prefix ending with one space).

Answer (score 1):

As you want to mimic is a (perl) regex, then use a `regex` not a `pattern`:

```
$ test="    z abcdefg"
$ regex='^ *z *(.*)'
$ [[ $test =~ $regex ]]
$ echo ">>${BASH_REMATCH[1]}<<"
>>abcdefg<<
```

The regex is an extended regex, not a fully PCRE.